# Testing the accuracy of a PLC current input module - economical approach?

Tags: resistors, analog, adc, plc

I don’t want to suggest a particular brand or model so to discourage a good universal approach. But let’s say the DUT here would be your typical industrial PLC module, a typical 4-20mA SAR ADC based, single-input/common ground module.

My plan so far is to find a tight tolerance set of resistors to test the current reported against a “known” current. I will only use resistors no better than the level of uncertainty documented in the module specifications when factoring gain and range error. If I go about it this way, my plan would be to deduct the observed (added) resistance from the resistors that these modules typically use on their channels (~150 ohm) that create the input voltage going into their mux. Is this a good approach, or are there better ways for reasonably cheap?

Thanks

Comment: All the 4 - 20 mA modules I've seen have 250 Ω input resistors to convert 20 mA into 5 V for the input ADC. Usually there's a jumper to switch from voltage measurement to current measurement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the 4 - 20 mA modules I've seen have 250 Ω input resistors to convert 20 mA into 5 V for the input ADC. Usually there's a jumper to switch from voltage measurement to current measurement.

[image]

*Figure 1. Vishay 250Ω Metal Film Resistor 0.5W ±0.1% RN65C2500BB14.*

Vishay, for example, make a 250 Ω 0.1% resistor which could be used as shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuY65R.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. A simple calibration check circuit. VM1 will read 5 V at 20 mA.*

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the usual way is to simply buy a calibrator from a reputable company and have it regularly calibrated to a traceable reference (often by a 3rd party calibration firm).

A short-term stable voltage source in conjunction with a precision ammeter and a short-term stable resistor OR a precision resistor and a precision voltmeter can be used as well.

The accuracy of the voltmeter and resistor or the ammeter will determine your total accuracy so long as the voltage source is short-term stable and reasonably low noise.

Any method that makes assumptions about the precise value of the load resistor internal to the input module would be suspect.

Before you can talk about how exactly to do this, you need to know what the rated specifications are that you are testing to, and the recommended conditions (eg. ambient temperature, warm-up time, supply voltage, and so on). Compare that to what trusted measuring instruments you already have available.